# Expo build:ios authentication with Apple account fails

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

I am pretty much stuck here. I have no idea why I get this error when trying executing `expo build:ios` :

```
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
spawn bash ENOENT
Error: spawn bash ENOENT
    at notFoundError (C:\Users\lucsw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (C:\Users\lucsw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\lucsw\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
```

I already tried creating a link with git and the project directory as seen here: [Windows 10, 'expo build:android\ fails with "Error: spawn /bin/cp ENOENT"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61445950/windows-10-expo-buildandroid-fails-with-error-spawn-bin-cp-enoent)

I also tried to delete the node_modules and reinstall them. Last, I tried `expo build:ios --clear-credentials` but this did not work either. [Failed authentication in Apple Developer Portal when execute expo build:ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403093/failed-authentication-in-apple-developer-portal-when-execute-expo-buildios)

`expo diagnostics`

```
Expo CLI 4.0.8 environment info:
    System:
      OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.19.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 6.14.9 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~39.0.2 => 39.0.4
      react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-dom: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.4.tar.gz => 0.63.2
      react-native-web: ~0.13.12 => 0.13.18
      react-navigation: ^4.4.3 => 4.4.3
    Expo Workflow: managed
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a paid Apple developer account?

Comment: @PrajwalKulkarni Yes

Comment: Are you using Windows OS?

Comment: @J.Doe Yea, after some hours trying I figured out what the problem was. So you basically need WSL 2 and in order to install WSL 2 you need Windows Pro and not Home.